# Converting a stopwatch time to milliseconds (regex)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, time

I'm trying to figure out the best way to convert a string containing a time to an integer number of milliseconds.  I'm using a suboptimal way using a bunch of preg_match()'s and some array handling, but I was wondering if there was an elegant way.

Here are some example stopwatch times (some wouldn't actually be seen on a stopwatch but need to be converted anyway):

```
3:34:05.81

34:05

5 (just 5 seconds)

89 (89 seconds)

76:05 (76 minutes, 5 seconds)
```

Millseconds will not extend past 2 decimal places.  You can give me an example using either PHP or Javascript regex functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using a *regexp* in this case.

Simply `explode` (split) the strings with ':', and perform a backward analysis - you always have seconds (and maybe milliseconds). Starting with array[lastelement] (seconds) then the previous...

For instance

**In PHP**

```
function getMilliseconds($input)
{
  $a = explode(':', $input);
  $n = count($a); // number of array items

  $ms = 0; // milliseconds result

  if ($n > 0)
  {
     $b = explode('.', $a[$n-1]);
     if (count ($b) > 1)
     {
       $m = $b[1];
       while (strlen($m) < 3) $m .= '0'; // ensure we deal with thousands
       $ms += $m;
     }
     $ms += $b[0] * 1000;

     if ($n > 1) // minutes
     {
       $ms += $a[$n-2] * 60 * 1000;

       if ($n > 2) // hours
       {
         $ms += $a[$n-3] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
       }
     }
  }
  return $ms;
}
```

**In JavaScript**

(just a PHP to Javascript conversion)

```
function getMilliseconds(input)
{
  var a = input.split(':');
  var n = a.length; // number of array items

  var ms = 0; // milliseconds result

  if (n > 0)
  {
     var b = a[n-1].split('.');
     if (b.length > 1)
     {
       var m = b[1];
       while (m.length < 3) m += '0'; // ensure we deal with thousands
       ms += m - 0; // ensure we deal with numbers
     }
     ms += b[0] * 1000;

     if (n > 1) // minutes
     {
       ms += a[n-2] * 60 * 1000;

       if (n > 2) // hours
       {
         ms += a[n-3] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
       }
     }
  }
  return ms;
}
```

Comment: I ended up with what I think makes it a little shorter -- do you see any pitfalls with this?

Comment: $times = explode(':', $time); $milliseconds = 1000*(array_pop($times) + array_pop($times)*60 + array_pop($times)*3600);

Comment: It's a lot shorter :-) Personally I prefer a clean code that deals with specific cases. In your solution, you do not take care of milliseconds: for instance `0.1` is not `1ms` it is actually `100ms`, as it should be read `0.100`. Besides you assume the order in which PHP will evaluate the `array_pop` - since there are only `+`, the *precedence* of operators does not intervene, but unless it is specifically written that in `a + b + c` PHP will start with `a`, then with `b` and finally with `c` (I don't know), it is a wrong assumption. Anyway the code reading is ambiguous, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Hmm.. Good points.  I always assumed it evaluated addition left-to-right but maybe it optimizes it differently sometimes.  I guess it goes with the old saying that it's bad to assume things ;)

Comment: Assuming things is a way to progress... but it has to be confirmed sometime. Regarding this point, it needs to be checked in the PHP doc, but again I don't advocate that kind of programming. But for instance assuming that in `if (a && b)`, `b` won't be evaluated if `a` is *false* is exact, and is very convenient (checking an array size before mentioning an item of the array in the condition for instance).

Answer (score 2):

I know it is solved.. but this is just an idea for javascript..

```
String.prototype.sw2ms = function() {
    var a = [86400000, 3600000, 60000, 1000];
    var s = this.split(/\:/g);
    var z = 0;

    while (s.length && a.length)
        z += a.pop() * Number(s.pop());

    return z;
};
alert("3:45:03.51".sw2ms());
alert("10:37".sw2ms());
alert("05.81".sw2ms());
alert("5".sw2ms());
```

Comment: Pretty slick -- the only thing I worry about is that adding properties to native objects might cause problems later (ie Google Maps).  But if you make it a standalone function, that looks nice!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex gives no clear advantage:

```
function parseStopwatchTime(time) {
    var splitTime = time.split(':'), // explode function in PHP
        secs = 0;

    if(time.length < 1 || time.length > 3) {
        return NaN;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
        secs *= 60;
        secs += +splitTime[i]; // JavaScript's unary plus operator
                               // casts from a string to a number
                               // so that it can safely be added.
    }

    return secs * 1000; // convert from seconds to milliseconds
}
```

More code would be needed if your stopwatch counts in days (still no regex needed), but just this is sufficient for hours, minutes, and (fractions of) a second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I wish I could check both answers as the accepted one, but since I can't I'm basing it on who answered first.